# Badging TitleArea Commands

Tags: codenameone

I have a form with a command added to the right side of the titlearea. I will like to badge the command icon with dynamic values.

[image: Thats the icon i will like to badge]

I have checked the documentation for Command and there seems to be no method to badge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the command to a component first:

```
Command cmd = tb.addMaterialCommandToRightSide(...);
Button btn = tb.findCommandComponent(cmd);
Container cnt = btn.getParent();
btn.remove();
FloatingActionButton fab = FloatingActionButton.createBadge("" + number);
cnt.add(badge.bindFabToContainer(btn, Component.RIGHT, Component.TOP));
```

Notice that this will only work once so you will need to save some of the components here and remove/replace them if you want to update the number.